# Angular performance: ng-show vs. dynamically recompile directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Let's say I have a boolean `format` that controls how a collection of items should be displayed by my directive. Depending on the value of `format`, my html changes radically.

So far I'm using two separate templates, and I dynamically recompile the directive whenever `format` changes, by using `$watch(format)` in the link function of the directive.

I wonder if it would be faster to use only one template, and split all my code between a big `ng-show="format"` and a `ng-hide="format"`. What's the best practice in that situation?

Comment: use ng-if, it removes the dom elements

Comment: It's not removing elements that I'm worried about it, but the time it takes to recreate them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$compile is expensive (relatively).  Your use case sounds like a candidate for ng-switch, so don't reinvent the wheel if ng-switch works for you.

However, inside your directive, you can cache the compilation of each template and then re-link them by calling the link function returned by $compile.  This would be pretty much as performant as ng-switch .

In pseudo code your link function would look like:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
     //create and cache your template link functions
     var format1link = $compile(template1);
     var format2link = $compile(template2);
     scope.$watch('format') {

         //call appropriate link function based on the value of format
         var newElement = format1link(scope);
         //or
         var newElement = format2link(scope);

         //replace element contents with newElement

     });
}
```

Comment: Neat! I was caching the html templates, but I didn't thought of caching the compiled templates themselves.

Comment: But you are right: ng-switch is much easier in that case. Otherwise I had to handle the asynchronous generation of the compiled templates, as well as the $watch listener, so it was a pain. And ng-switch seems really fast so far.

Comment: Glad to help.  9 times out of 10 angular already does what you are trying to do!